# Grabble project sync failed

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android Studio. When I launch the program, there is the following error.
"Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:10.+"

I have checked the SDK manager, Android Support Library and Android are installed.

Maybe my question appears to be stupid but I didn't find any answer.

[EDIT] I changed the

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:10.+
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
```

Now I have more than 400 lines of not found files:
http://pastebin.com/Sa4scRH1

Answer (score 1):

In you build.gradle you have in the dependency section a line containing this string:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:10.+'
```

replace it with this one:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
```

You are using there a quite old version of the compat library just use the newest one v21.0.2. If this still fails install the support repository from the SDK Manager.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have a 400 lines error messages about resources which are not found. I thought Android Studio was easy to install and use.

Comment: Please show the rest of your build.gradle, I think that you need to change the target skd version to 21 too.